# Pass data from dropdown Button Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i wanted to get the dropdown widget out of there and put it to another place and pass the data to the another page which firestore use it to Query! ,tried many ways:( help! thanks.

```html
String _currentlySelectedlanguage="USA";

  final List<String> _dropdownValueslanguage = ["USA", "India"];

  Widget dropdownWidgetlanguage() {
    return DropdownButton(
      isExpanded: false,
      value: _currentlySelectedlanguage,
      onChanged: (String newvalue) {
        setState(() {
          _currentlySelectedlanguage = newvalue;
        });
      },
      items: _dropdownValueslanguage
          .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(value),
                value: value,
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
  

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getData(String filter) async {
    final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore
        .collection('slideshow')
        .where("lang", isEqualTo: _currentlySelectedlanguage)
        .get();
    return snapshot.docs;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
class Code extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CodeState createState() => _CodeState();
}

String currentLanguage; //updated

class _CodeState extends State<Code> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        dropdownWidgetlanguage(),
        FutureBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
            future: getData(_currentlySelectedlanguage),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => snapshot.data[index].data()['name'],);
              }else{
                return Container();
              }
            },)
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget dropdownWidgetlanguage() {
    return DropdownButton(
      isExpanded: false,
      value: _currentlySelectedlanguage,
      onChanged: (String newvalue) {
        setState(() {
          _currentlySelectedlanguage = newvalue;
          currentLanguage = newvalue; //updated
        });
      },
      items: _dropdownValueslanguage
          .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(value),
                value: value,
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
  String _currentlySelectedlanguage;

  final List<String> _dropdownValueslanguage = ["USA", "India"];

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getData(String filter) async {
    final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore
        .collection('slideshow')
        .where("lang", isEqualTo: filter)
        .get();
    return snapshot.docs;
  }
}
```

---

```
class SecondClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Class2State createState() => _Class2State();
}

class _Class2State extends State<SecondClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(currentLanguage),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir , but how i can call currentLanguage in other pages ?! , i tried many things not worked :(